# How to find dictionaries in one list but not in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Say we have 2 lists of dictionaries L1 and L2.

I want to have a list of dictionaries that are in L2 but not in L1. In my case, I have L1 is a subset of L2 so im not sure if that fact can be used to make any optimizations.

Comment: try using `set`

Comment: Go fot set! Set don't have repetitive elements.

Comment: but I know if you had a list of lists, set doesn't work for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution

```
[_dict for _dict in l1 if _dict not in l2]
```

This will get the dictionaries which are in l1 but not in l2

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension:

```
L1 = [{1: 2, 2: 3}, {2: 3, 3: 4}]
L2 = [{1: 2, 2: 3}, {4: 5, 5: 6}]
print([d for d in L2 if d not in L1])
```

This outputs:

```
[{4: 5, 5: 6}]
```

Or if you have a large list of dicts, you should convert `L1` to a set of tuples for efficient membership lookup:

```
set1 = set(tuple(d.items()) for d in L1)
print([d for d in L2 if tuple(d.items()) not in set1])
```

Comment: You can optimize the runtime for large collections of dicts by operating on sets of `tuple(d.items())`. Convert the members of the final result back to dicts in the end.